# Discord.js bot ban command not send message. discord.js 11.6.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I’m Spanish so my English might be a little rusty. I have a discord bot with a command that ban a member and sends him a message with the server that has been banned, reasons, etc. But a few days ago I realized that my bot did not send the message, but I have not changed the code since the last stable release, where the bot sent the message to the banned. When I delete the line that ban the user (`message.guild.ban(mentioned, {reason: reason});`) the bot sends the message without any error. You have below the command code[, and here you have the error that displays the command prompt.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4O9H.png)

```
module.exports = {
name: 'condenar',
description: "Comando principal del verdugo que avisa al condenado. Se suele usar antes del v!ban",
execute(message, args){

  if (message.member.roles.find("name", "Monarca")){
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    var embedColor = '#ff0000' 
    const moment = require("moment");
    var missingPermissionsEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed() 
        .setColor(embedColor)
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setTitle('Permisos insuficientes!')
        .setDescription('Necesitas el permiso `MANAGE_MESSAGES` para usar este comando!')
        .setTimestamp();
    var missingArgsEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed() 
        .setColor(embedColor)
        .setAuthor(message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL)
        .setTitle('Argumentos insuficientes!')
        .setDescription('Uso: v!condenar <@User> <Motivo>')
        .setTimestamp();
    if(!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return message.channel.send(missingPermissionsEmbed); 
    let mentioned = message.mentions.users.first();
    if (mentioned.id == 615199347398672392) return message.channel.send('No ahorcare a mi padre.');
    if(!mentioned) return message.channel.send(missingArgsEmbed); 
    let reason = args.slice(1).join(' ') 
    if(!reason) return message.channe.send(missingArgsEmbed); 
    var ahorcNumber = Math.random();
    var ahorcEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed() 
        .setColor(embedColor)
        .setDescription(`ID del mensaje: ${message.id}`)
        .setTitle(`**Ahorcamiento ${message.guild.name}**`)
        .addField('Ahorcado por:', message.author.tag)
        .addField('Motivo:', reason)
        .addField('ID del ahorcamiento:', `**${ahorcNumber}** *necesitaras este numero para ver la info del ahorcamiento mas adelante.`)
        .attachFiles(['./img/ahorcado.gif'])
        .setFooter(`En: ${moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm A", Date.now())}`)
        .setTimestamp();
    mentioned.send(ahorcEmbed); 
    message.channel.send(ahorcEmbed);
    message.guild.ban(mentioned, {reason: reason});
    var dir = `./files/${message.guild.id}`;
    var fs = require('fs');
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
        fs.mkdirSync(`${dir}/warns`, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
        fs.mkdirSync(`${dir}/ahorcamientos`, function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
    };
        fs.mkdirSync(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${ahorcNumber}`);
        fs.writeFile(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${ahorcNumber}/ahorcado.txt`, `${mentioned.username}(${mentioned.id})`, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
        fs.writeFile(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${ahorcNumber}/Author.txt`, `${message.author.username}(${message.author.id})`, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
        fs.writeFile(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${ahorcNumber}/Motivo.txt`, `${reason}`, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
            if(err) console.log('error', err);
          });
          if (!fs.existsSync(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${mentioned.id}.txt`)){
            fs.writeFile(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${mentioned.id}.txt`, 1, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
                if(err) console.log('error', err);
              });
          }else{
              fs.readFile(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${mentioned.id}.txt`, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
              var x = +data;
              var y = 1;
              var z = x + y;
              fs.writeFile(`${dir}/ahorcamientos/${mentioned.id}.txt`, `${z}`, 'utf8', function(err, result) {
                  if(err) console.log('error', err);
              });
              });
          };


    }else{
    message.channel.send('Tienes que tener el rol `Monarca` para poder usar este comando');


};
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, users may not be allowed to send messages to them in DM :)

And you has error here, missing `n` in `channel`:

```js
return message.channe.send(missingArgsEmbed);
```

Comment: no because when I delete the line that ban, the user recive the message

Comment: @4lon3ly0 Because user can not allow send message to him, if they has no same servers with message sender. So, you can send message to him if he is on the server. But can\`t after ban him. Better notify user and then ban.

Comment: it did not work, it was the first I tried. You can see in the code that first it sends the embed, and then it ban.

Comment: If it\`s happen on specific user, so it\`s not a code problem. It`s user confidentiality setting.

Comment: I will try with a friend, but I think that it is not the problem.

Comment: the friend recived the message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was a problem with the confidentiality settings of my testing account. Thanks to everyone.